# Export many plots from a matrix from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, loops, matrix, export-to-excel

I have a matrix names df with 2 columns.

```
         AVELOX5  AVELOX7
Jan 2009  1.00000  6.00000
Feb 2009  2.00000  4.00000
Mar 2009  5.00000  3.00000
Apr 2009 34.00000  1.00000
May 2009  7.00000  2.00000
Jun 2009  6.00000 34.00000
Jul 2009  8.00000 34.00000
Aug 2009  8.00000 53.00000
Sep 2009  9.00000  6.00000
Oct 2009  4.00000  7.00000
Nov 2009 23.00000  9.00000
Dec 2009 12.42851 10.33471
Jan 2010 12.78912 10.80950
Feb 2010 13.14972 11.28429
Mar 2010 13.51032 11.75908
Apr 2010 13.87092 12.23387
May 2010 14.23152 12.70866
Jun 2010 14.59212 13.18345
Jul 2010 14.95273 13.65824
Aug 2010 15.31333 14.13303
Sep 2010 15.67393 14.60781
Oct 2010 16.03453 15.08260
Nov 2010 16.39513 15.55739
```

I want to export the plots from every column separated to excel.
I don't know if i will need a loop..and i don't know what the code will be.
With the code `plot(df[,1])` i have the plot for `AVELOX5` and with the code `plot(df[,2])` i have the second plot.

I want with one code( maybe a loop ) to export every column from R to excel.. Consider that i want the loop cause i want to do the same thing in a matrix with 80 columns..so it will take me time to text `plot(df[,1])...plot(df[,80])`.

The second part of my question is : how i export the 'n' plots from R in an excel.

Comment: [This post might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948776/exporting-histogram-from-r-to-excel). I think the steps would be, make image files - jpegs - in a loop, then use some Excel R package that can import images.

Comment: Avoid using Loop ! use lapply to do something across columns of df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be divided by two.

Step 1 Save plots into a local drive. It can be done as following.

```
lapply(1:ncol(df), function(x) {
  png(paste(x, ".png", sep = ""))
  plot(df[,x])
  dev.off()
})
# or
for(x in 1:ncol(df)) {
  png(paste(x, ".png", sep = ""))
  plot(df[,x])
  dev.off()  
}
```

Step 2 Export into Excel

Actually I'm not sure if there is a way to do so in R. You would have to use VBA as it allows inserting photos ([LINK](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/6485-excel-a-macro-to-insert-pictures)).

Answer (score 0):

The below loop should automatically create each plot required and save it to a .jpg file. As far as I'm aware there isn't a way to export a plot to an Excel document. You can save in different formats if required, more details about that [here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/saving.html)

```
for (i in 1:80) {
jpeg('i.jpg')
plot(df[,i])
dev.off()
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer.